# Travis CI for Github?

Tags: github, travis-ci

I have a minimalistic .travis.yml file, which consists of:

```
php:
  - "5.4"
```

But on console, it fails with:

```
$ rvm use default --install --binary --fuzzy
Using /home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448
$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [x86_64-linux]
$ rvm --version
rvm 1.21.3 (latest-minor) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
$ gem --version
2.0.3
$ rake
rake aborted!
No Rakefile found (looking for: rakefile, Rakefile, rakefile.rb, Rakefile.rb)
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The command "rake" exited with 1.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

It's defaulting to ruby when I have specified PHP as the language, whats wrong here ?

Answer (score 2):

Try making your .travis.yml a little less minimalist:

```
language: php
php:
  - 5.4
```

Also, using php with travis uses [phpenv](https://github.com/CHH/phpenv) instead of rvm

Read up more on it here:
http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/languages/php/

Comment: @SophieMackeral If you have more information or progress, I'd love to hear about it. I found this example repo, maybe it will help you figure out what is wrong: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci-php-example

Answer (score 0):

It took me some time to figure out so I'm posting here [for anyone else that may encounter this in the future](http://xkcd.com/979/):

I had no idea that, in YAML, whitespace has meaning. Tabs/spaces (and possibly `\r\n` ("windows") vs `\n` ("linux")) matter. [A simple change I did to my .yml file](https://github.com/RobThree/TwoFactorAuth/commit/cf828a05de8bf124f2df41cf001c7b1a8e6692a7) made a night-and-day difference (build failed before, built correctly after).

Lesson learned here: YAML cares about whitespace. Make sure your .travis.yml file is correct!